# How do I edit the "info boxes" next to input parameters in ArcGIS toolboxes?

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcpy

When using the toolboxes, there are info icons that appear next to parameters that I can't find how to edit. I referenced another toolbox and there was nothing in the execution or validation code related to them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Catalog pane, right-click the tool and select "Edit Metadata":

[image: Screenshot showing a tool's context menu with "Edit Metadata" highlighted]

This will allow you to edit the metadata, including tool help information. To add info-box/tool-tip text, find the "Syntax" heading and click to expand the parameter ("Input" in the screenshot below):

[image: Tool metadata view with parameter "Input" circled]

In the "Dialog Explanation" box, type in the description of the parameter that you would like to appear in the tool-tip. Save your changes using the button in the ribbon. Note that you may need to type something in the "Tags" box near the top of the form before you can save.

[image: Tool metadata view with "Dialog Explanation" and "Save" highlighted]

Now, when you hover over the parameter in the Geoprocessing pane, you should see your newly-added documentation:

[image: Geoprocessing tool example with parameter tool-tip visible]